# Is there any difference between the tags asking questions and questions?

Tags: discussion

These are meta tags. Should they be marekd as synonyms? Is there any difference between the tags asking questions and questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are auto-generated tags that come with meta, so I don't think there is any need to merge them.